# How to know the url of installed application on websphere

Tags: java, web-applications, websphere-7

I am a novice to web-sphere application server.

I am not able to figure out where I can get the url of application installed and what is default port number used for http requests.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: check this url(http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsdoc400/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.iseries.doc/info/ae/ae/adrportbase.htm)

Comment: http://localhost:9080/ivt/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The port numbers used can be specific to you particular WAS installation and depends on the topology as well. You can either try default 9080 or look for the port number in WAS configuration. What you're looking for is *WC_defaulthost* for http and *WC_defaulthost_secure* for https.

If you have access to WAS admin console, navigate to Servers => WebSphere Application Servers and choose your server. Then look for Communication sections which contains Ports.

Of course it is always possible to look for the port number on disk. For example:
`<WAS_HOME>/profiles/<PROFILE_NAME>/logs/AboutThisProfile.txt` is generated when creating the profile, so contains the port numbers as well. Then you can take a look at `<WAS_HOME>/profiles/<PROFILE_NAME>/config/cells/<CELL_NAME>/nodes/<NODE_NAME>/serverindex.xml`

Comment: Okay, that's the port. But what about the remainder of the URL?

Comment: "Then look for Communication sections which contains Port"

And from that list of 20 ports, which one is the one with the app?

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned by Michal in his answer, the port can be found in the Administrative console under Servers -> Server types -> WebSphere application servers -> (your server name) -> Ports (in the Connunication section).

The remainder of the URL can be looked up and configured under Applications -> Application Types -> WebSphere enterprise applications -> (your application name) -> Context Root For Web Modules (in the Web Module Properties section).

Comment: I followed exactly. WS says its installed and working. I can see other app on port 9080. This gives 404 please fixed.

Answer (score 3):

None of the answer's worked for me as my application used a virtual host.

In Websphere admin console:

1. Navigate to `Environment`
2. then `Virtual hosts`
3. Select your application host
4. Go to `Host Aliases` and there you will find the port number.

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no way to do this directly. You have to piecemeal evidence you find in your project and Admin Console and try possibly 100s of URLs before you'll find the correct one.

Sometimes you can get Tomcat to display URLs but you'll need to follow some further config steps.